# Modal Closes and Reloads Page Before Firebase Login is Done

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a login with Firebase. What happens is that when I submit the modal form with the username and password, my async login function does not have enough time to complete and the website gets reloaded before the function has finished. When I change the onsubmit to "return false", it all works and the user is logged in, but the form is not closed anymore programmatically. What I want is that it waits for the Firebase login function and then closes the page and reloads it.

Here is my code:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='block'" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="admin-button">Admin</button>
  <div id="login" class = "modal">
    <form name="myForm" class="modal-content animate" method="post">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'"class="close" title="Close Modal" style="color:#a00000;">&times;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2 id="admin-title">Admin Login</h2>
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="admin-code" name="password" required>
        <button type="submit" id="login-button" onclick="validateForm()">Login</button>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn" style="margin:10px">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And this is for validateForm() function:

```
async function validateForm(){
  console.log("inside validate Form");
  var x = document.forms.myForm.uname.value;
  var y = document.forms.myForm.password.value;

  alert(x);
  alert(y);
  signInWithFirebase(x,y);

  CheckIfSignedIn();
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the `CheckIfSignedIn` function closes the modal as it's not clear from the code provided where exactly this is being done.

If `signInWithFirebase` is making an async call to your Firebase then `validateForm` needs to `await` it. Here is some pseudo-code showing how you might do this.

```
async function validateForm(){
  ...
  await signInWithFirebase(x,y);

  CheckIfSignedIn();
}
```

```
async function signInWithFirebase(x, y){
    try {
        const user = await firedb.auth().signInWithUsernameAndPassword(x, y);
        return user;
    } catch(error) {
        return error.message;
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with Firebase itself but the principle is the same for all async code.